# Cache invalidation in Ehcache

Tags: ehcache

I am using Ehcache in Hibernate.

How can I notify the cache that the database has changed? How can I invalidate the cached data? How can I programmatically achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

What do exactly mean? There are 2 ways to make a change in the database: inside the app & outside the app

Inside the app you can trigger easily an invalidation.  The second one is a harder to solve. Cache elements are stored with a key and based on that key you can delete it.

```
CacheManager manager = CacheManager.getInstance();
cache = manager.getCache(cacheName);
cache.remove(key);

or 

cache.removeAll();
```

Depending how you configured ehcache of course.  But you need to know the name of the cache that holds the object.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can **invalidate all EhCache items** without bothering what the individual cache names are:

```
CacheManager manager = CacheManager.getInstance();

String[] names = manager.getCacheNames();

for (String name : names)
{
    Cache cache = manager.getCache(name);

    cache.removeAll();
}
```

Comment: While this may have worked well at the time of writing, I had to replace [`.getCache`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager.html#getCache\(java.lang.String\)) with [`.getEhcache`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager.html#getEhcache\(java.lang.String\)), and [`Cache`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html) with [`Ehcache`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/hibernate/EhCache.html).  Otherwise, `.getCache` returns `null` even for caches which exist.

Comment: Didn't work for me as my configurations being [hibernate ehcache timeToLiveSeconds not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18914668/432903)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
CacheManager.create().clearAll()
```

It will clear all caches in CacheManager.

To clear only one particular cache, get it from cache manager and remove all elements:

```
CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.create();
Ehcache cache = cacheManager.getEhcache(cacheConfiguration.getName());
cache.removeAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Set cache expiration so data is refreshed as or more often than the database changes .

Also you can update in cache only elements that change in the database .

Comment: Can you explain how to set "cache expiration"?

Comment: Cache Expiration is defined by the timeToLiveSeconds field in ehcache.xml ... when the value of timeToLiveSeconds is elapsed , the cached element is considered invalid and will be fetched from the source when requested ... fetching will incur caching thus resetting the timer of timeToLiveSeconds ...

For Example :


<cache name="thisCache" maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000" eternal="false" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20" timeToIdleSeconds="500" timeToLiveSeconds="900" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" diskPersistent="false" transactionalMode="off"> </cache>

Comment: not applicable to persistent cache entries that never change

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want to remove a specific cache (eg:employeeCache)

```
@Autowired
CacheManager cacheManager;
```

place where you want to invalidate cache, use below code

```
    Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("employeeCache");
    cache.removeAll();
```