# How to clear a specific cache region : ehcache

Tags: ehcache

I have a ehcache configuration like the below :

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<cache
name="reg1"
maxElementsInMemory="100000"
eternal="false"
overflowToDisk="true"
timeToLiveSeconds="1">
</cache>
<cache
name="reg2"
maxElementsInMemory="1000000"
eternal="false"
overflowToDisk="true"
timeToLiveSeconds="100"/>
</ehcache>
```

I am unable to figure out how I can clear just "reg1".
I have seen a method to clear all but not a specific region.
Anyone who has figured out how to do this, please share.

Thanks

Comment: I have for now used the "clearAllStartingWith" method

Comment: Share the solution if you solved it?

Comment: No.Still using the same method.

Comment: Have you tried [clearing cache using cacheManager in java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6198959/432903) to remove a particular region with the help of `cache.removeAll();`. Check if that works. And what do you mean by `clearAllStartingWith` method.

Comment: I have not tried that.http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager.html#clearAllStartingWith(java.lang.String)

Comment: which version of EhCache are you using? I don't see `clearAllStartingWith()` in `version 3.1.1`. There is only `clearAll()`

Comment: ehcache version 2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Ehcache documentation :

http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.4.4/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html#removeAll()

Removes all cached items.