# In Hibernate If changes happen in Database side. then how it will reflect on UI side if am using cache

Tags: hibernate

In Web_Application am using Spring and Hibernate. So if i search something then in my first request it will Hit the database and in second same request it will get the result from cache. but what happen if i manually change that particular value from database from database side. Change will reflect or not in the UI.

Comment: please add more info to clarify your particular use case, which chahe are you referring to?

Comment: EH Cache(second level cache)

Comment: basically you will lneed to [invalidate the cahce.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830497/cache-invalidation-in-ehcache)

Comment: If some user or process make changes directly in database, then  is there  any way that second level cache update itself.